# What is wrong with the iterator for a tree data structure?

Tags: javascript

I am trying to implement a naive iterator for a tree data structure. Why is the name of the last node in the tree ('level 2: B') not printed to the console? What is wrong with the iterator?

```js
class Node {
    constructor(name) {
        this.name = name;
        this.child = [];
    }

    add(name) {
        const node = new Node(name);
        this.child.push(node);
        return node;
    }

    [Symbol.iterator]() {
        return this;
    }

    next() {
        if (this.current === undefined) {
            this.current = 0;
            return {
                done: (this.child.length > 0) ? false : true,
                value: this
            }
        }

        const other = this.child[this.current].next();
        if (other.done) {
            this.current++;
            if (this.current < this.child.length) {
                other.done = false;
            }
        }
        return other;
    }
}

const root = new Node('level 0');
let node = root.add('level 1: A');
node.add('level 2: A');
root.add('level 1: B');
root.add('level 1: C');
node = root.add('level 1: D');
node.add('level 2: B');

for (const node of root) {
    console.log(node.name);
}

console.log(root);
```

This should be so simple, but it's not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because the last node has no children, thus you return:

```
 return {
   done: true,
   value: this
 }
```

Now because *done* is set to `true`, this is not a *yielded* value of the iterator, but the *return* value of it. You could get that if you would manually call `.next()`, but `for..of` ignores it.

The solution would be to *yield* `this` first (set `done` to `false`), then *return*.

But actually, `Node` shouldn't be an iterator but an iterable, and then it can easily be implemented:

```
 [Symbol.iterator]*() {
    yield this;
    for(const child of this.child)
       yield* child;
}
```